# Persist file-based data cache for max of 1 minute in PHP

Tags: php, caching, file-io, disqus

I've written some PHP code based on a [sample on Github](https://github.com/disqus/DISQUS-API-Recipes/blob/master/php/get_and_write_popular_threads_to_cache.php) to access the DISQUS API, get a JSON response, and write it to a flat `*.txt` file as a cache. I also have [similar code from Github](https://github.com/disqus/DISQUS-API-Recipes/blob/master/php/get_popular_threads_from_cache.php) to open that cache file and output the results to the page. Right now I'm having trouble finding a way to logically persist and/or evict that cache file. I would like my code that access that cache file to read from the file if it was modified/created in the last 60 seconds. If it's read from beyond 60 seconds from its creation/modification date, re-create it with new data. So my underlying goal is to persist that cache for 1 minute max. How can I accomplish this with PHP?

FYI, I'm an ASP.NET developer and can easily do this with the native C# caching tools but I'm not familiar with the PHP approaches.

**Edit**: Per the comment below, here are more details about my expected uses:

- Average size of data to be cached: a few kb of HTML (5-10kb)
- Total size of data to be cached: a few kb of HTML (5-10kb)
- Rate at which I expect requests against the cache to occur: I'm not really sure! The point here is to not hit the 1000 request limit per hour for the DISQUS API, so I'm using a text file to cache every minute.

so as to perhaps get more guidance on a good solution

Comment: There are a number of caching options availabe that have handy PHP libraries.  You should should add to your question information such as average size of data to be cached, total size of data to be cached, and rate at which you expect requests against the cache to occur, so as to perhaps get more guidance on a good solution.

Comment: Good point. Updated. Thanks!

Comment: Your average data size and total size are equal.  Does that mean you are only going to cache one item at a time?

Comment: Again, they're roughly equal and I don't know the exact sizes. I'm calling the DISQUS API and getting back a JSON response for the 5 most trending articles. So yes, each time I need to evict the cache and re-create it, it will make a fresh call to DISQUS and potentially get the same data back, or maybe slightly different JSON. But its very little JSON (5-10 kb). Does that make sense?